# Nestjs circular dependency using forwardref

Tags: typescript, nestjs, circular-dependency

Hi guys i am getting circular dependency error on nestjs
i tried using the `forwardref` but that doesn't help me

```
// AuthModule 
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_DURATION },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
// UserModule
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => AuthModule)],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

In the Service i am accessing the other service like this

```
private readonly authService: AuthService,
```

== CMD ERROR ==
[Nest] 2788  - 06/10/2023, 12:56:50 PM     LOG [InjectorLogger] Nest encountered an undefined dependency. This may be due to a circular import or a missing dependency declaration.
[Nest] 2788  - 06/10/2023, 12:56:50 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (PrismaService, ?, CONFIGURATION(app)). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the UserModule context.

Potential solutions:

- Is UserModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?

  ```
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
  ```

Why i got circular dependency !!

Comment: give it a shot: [Circular Dependencies in NestJS and how to Avoid Them](https://trilon.io/blog/avoiding-circular-dependencies-in-nestjs)

Comment: Please share what the UserService constructor looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the @Inject() in the constructor (where did i import the services)
you can see more in the docs

Comment: Can you show your working code?

Answer (score 3):

**This answer can't help you solve the problem, but it gives you a better understanding of the inter-module connections**

You can integrate [nestjs-spelunker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-spelunker)

*Sometimes you want to visualize the module inter-dependencies so you can better reason about them. The SpelunkerModule has a graph method that builds on the output of the explore method by generating a doubly-linked graph where each node represents a module and each edge a link to that module's dependencies or dependents.*

Comment: The Spelunker isn't show any log, because Nest fails before

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the constructor:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => TestService))
  privado testService: TestService,
)
```

Alternatively you can also use:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(REQUEST)
  privado testService: TestService,
)
```

Although I think it's better to use the first one, it also depends on what you are using.

if you are using pipes I recommend you to check this issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4367

Answer (score -2):

Try to avoid calling services from other services. Follow the path of reducing intermodule connections

Comment: It is a must to not duplicate the code

Comment: @MohammadARZ duplicate code is fine. Are you duplicating _logic_?

Comment: The suggestion given is indeed a good practice for software development in general, but it might not be practical in the context of NestJS or in a situation where services naturally need to interact with each other.